# Creating function skeleton keyboard shortcut

Tags: android, function, ide, shortcut

When I write first letters of a function or class, it shows the function referance. From there, there was a shortcut to create the skeleton of the function but I couldn't remember it and couldn't find it in the official website of Android Studio.
This was a thing also in other IDE's, Can you let me know what it is called? I am relatively new in programming. 
I look forward for your kind answers.

Comment: Can you show an example of this feature? Show what you type and what the feature will generate for you after you press the shortcut.

Comment: Isn't that just the autocomplete thingy? When you press enter it should implement the abstract class/interface by writing stubs.

Comment: Oh you should hit enter? Wow this works thank you.